# OpenSearch ISM: What state take the index after force_merge action execution

Tags: opensearch

Have a question related to action force_merge, the official doc says: "This operation attempts to set the index to a read-only state before starting the merging process."

- What happens with the state of the index after the force_merge action is completed?
- Does it stay in read_only?